# Firestore realtime listener and cost

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to understand the cost of using Firestore realtime listeners. In my case it is for an editor (realtime collaborating).

Words in an editor may correspond to documents in Firestore. And a document in an editor may be a collection in Firestore.

There may be thousands of words in a document in the editor.

Each time a user opens a document in the edtor a snapshot for the corresponding collection must be set up, something like this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web_3):

```js
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

I am a bit worried about the cost for this call. And I can see no way to charge users for this. (I think I read some years ago that the cost for this call was very low, but if I remember correctly now it has changed.)

Can someone clarify this for me, please?

---

EDIT: Trying to make my question more clear.

1. Let us say that there a 5000 words in a document in the editor.
2. This will be 5000 Firestore documents.
3. Opening the document in the editor will call the Firestore to get a snapshot and setup a listener (see code example above).
4. As I understand it this will now be charged as reading 5000 Firestore documents.

My question is about point 4 above. Do I understand that correctly?

And what happens when the users reopens this editor document? Will there be a charge for 5000 Firestore documents each time?

(I am expecting the users to open each documents many times due to the nature of the app I am writing.)

---

EDIT 2:
Since I believe it is now clear that the code above actually will be charged for 5000 reads (see point 4 above) I think I now can ask the real question without raising too much confusion:

**How is this handled when `firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()` has been done?**

Is there any point where this can be alleviated? It looks to me like Firestore `collection` might be such a point. (Last change time could be stored for a collection, perhaps. I am not sure. But I think this must be done on the Firestore side, not in my code, or?) Is something like this implemented in Firestore?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what sort of answer you're expecting here, or where you are stuck computing the cost of your query.  You also seem to have a second question here related to accounting and user billing.  I suggest narrowing this question down to a single, discrete question with clear data to work with.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear see [Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#pricing_by_location) which states **Document reads: $0.06 per 100,000 documents**.  So reading 100,000 documents  is $0.06. Then add in the stored data pricing shown at that same link. Is there something more?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have tried to clarify the question. (And yes, there is a second question. I leave that out for now to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @Jay Thanks, yes, please see the additions I made to the question. I am asking about the price for setting up the snapshot.

Comment: I'm still confused.  I'm not sure what you mean by the "firestore editor". Is your question about how the Firestore **web console** works when you use it, or how the code you provided works?  It should just be about one or the other.  They don't work the same.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't understand how the console is involved. I am asking about code such as the one I provided. Please see my update to the question, point 4.

Comment: What is the "editor" you refer to?  That's entirely unclear to me.  I don't understand what is involved in each step.

Comment: @DougStevenson The editor is my app. You could think of my app just like a text document editor (though it is a bit different). A text document in the editor is mapped to a collection in Firestore. Each word the user see in the app corresponds to a document in that collection in Firestore.

Comment: Dear someone voting to close this. Are you sure you understand the question. Please explain yourself.

Comment: The point of persistence is to allow a user to continue to interact with your app in situations where the internet connection is interrupted - like when a user is going through a tunnel. If they write a bunch of data during that time, when the connection re-establishes, it writes that data to firebase and you are charged for it. Read's behave similarly. You should not rely on persistence to alleviate any billing and fully count on every 100,000 reads to cost .06.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too clear on what your confusion is.  But the simple fact of the matter is this:

If you make query that fetches 5000 documents from Firestore, you will be charged 5000 document reads.

There's nothing you're showing here that indicates that anything else would happen.  Every time your code executes that query, you will be charged.

Comment: Thanks, but what about persistent storage? I think that can be implemented a bit differently to alleviate this. I have no idea how this works now in cases like this. (Firestore collections is a technical point where this perhaps is possible to implement by the Firestore developers. )

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2 to the quesion.

Comment: Persistence doesn't change the way that queries are performed while online.  You can read more about how it actually works. https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329

Comment: Thanks, the article is great. I just read it through quickly. However I didn't see anything about listeners and caching. If I use "{ source: 'cache' }" with fallback to server when reading the "snapShot", how will the listener behave?

Comment: Queries targeting cache don't fall back to server.  It's the other way around - queries go to the server by default, and if not available, fall back to cache.

Comment: Yes, but it's that the logic for listeners too? If the cache comes from a query to the server then I don't see why the listener can't continue listening to the server. Or is that about freeing up resources? (And what is then the server side logic?)

Comment: Listeners can't target cache only.  They always try to use the server, then use the cache if not available, but always keep trying the server intentally.  If you have a new question, please post it separately, as you've gone pretty far out of scope of your original question now.  Stack Overflow is meant to handle one question at a time, in order to be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: Ok. In my vocabulary I would say listeners are hooks that are setup on the server. But maybe I am misunderstanding something totally in the case of Firestore. I have no idea how this is built (and that is why I am asking).

Comment: They are set up on the server, but data can come from cache in the event that the server isn't available.

Comment: I guess this is for local writes? But you are right. This is another discussion, but I don't know what to do. The handling of listeners does not seem to be optional for cases like mine. I am quite frustrated at the moment since I hoped that the Firestore developers should have changed this by now. But I might be misunderstanding something. What I imagine is something like "may I please continue using the hooks that you did setup for me for this listener before? I already have data until 2020-08-14T23:39:20.734Z". It is really a suggestion to the Firestore developers. Are they interested?

Comment: If you have a suggestion, file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

According to firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations),

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

So that means, the firestore cost for this is quite lower than performing repetitive fetches on intervals, and it hasn't changed anytime recent.

Regarding how to charge users for this, the handler to `onSnapshot` is called with a docSnapshot object that contains reference to which documents were added, modified or deleted, so should be easy to infer billing from that

Comment: Thanks Jay. Yes I am aware of the cost for each read, but I am not sure how setting up the snapshot and listener counts. (I might have misread the documentation when Firestore was new. Or something has changed.)

Comment: You get billed for every document that matches your query the first time. Then upon subsequent change to any one of those documents, you get billed for an extra read

Comment: Thanks, yes that is how I am reading it now (and that was why I am asking). But that means that every time any of the users reopens the document in the editor we will be charged again for the whole Firefox collection, or?

Comment: The Firestore web console will bill you for document reads, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am not sure I understand what you mean. Please see the update I made to my question.

Comment: Jay, as I said to @DougStevenson in a comment on his answer there seems to me to be a technical way to limit the number of fetched documents when Firestore offline persistence, firebase.firestore().enablePersistence(), has been enabled. But I do not know if this has been implemented.

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2 to the question.

Comment: From the much I know, offline persistence will most likely not reduce cost appreciably. And might undermine the UX of your app since I understand its a multi-user real-time editor of some kind. Might I suggest that you reconsider your structure? You can still achieve real-time feature without making every word a document

Comment: You could make the entire content of the editor a document containing an array of the words. You don't really lose much by doing that and it will save you a ton

Comment: @JayCodist Yes, I have considered that structure instead. However I hoped that Google would fix this. (Fixing this on the `collection` level in Firestore seems rather easy with offline persistence, but the Firestore developers knows of course better. I hoped they might shed some light on this.) Fixing it on my side have at least two disadvantages: network traffic and complexity. Both are trouble for me since I want this to work on slow networks and rather cheap Android phones.

Comment: I understand @Leo. I still think your best option is the structure change